# Error - Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I am using SCCM 2016, Windows Server 2012. I am using the code below to move a collection to another folder. I get the error message `Move-CMObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.`

I've researched the error via Google but I still can't understand how 'InputObject' is null. I have seen other PS script formatted the same way and it is a working script. I'd like to know how to fix this and move the collection to another folder.

```
$sitecode = "123"
$colltomove = "SLS00287"
$destcollfolder = '$($sitecode):\DeviceCollection\Test Operational' 

$collID = Get-CMCollection -Name $colltomove
Move-CMObject -InputObject $collID -FolderPath $destcollfolder
```

Comment: Have you verified that `Get-CMCollection` actually returns anything? Do you see anything on the screen if you just run `Get-CMCollection -Name $colltomove`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen nothing shows up. No error, no output. It just processes command and goes back to starting point. Additionally I ran the Get-CMCollection -Name and put in the collection ID. I know this is correct and it exists but it still did the same as above.

Comment: Well, there's your explanation as to why `$collID` is `$null` :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so how do I fix it? I know it actually contains a collection. If I add Return $colltomove it returns SLS00287

Comment: If I run $Collection = "SLS00287"
Get-CMDeviceCollection -CollectionId $Collection | select Name, CollectionID it returns the name of the collection and the collection id.

Comment: There you go :) `Get-CMDeviceCollection -CollectionId $collection |Move-CMObject -FolderPath $destcollfolder`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen now I get Move-CMObject : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '$($sitecode)' does not exist.

Comment: Use `"` (double-quotes) for the `$destcollfolder` variable instead of `'` - otherwise powershell won't expand the `$sitecode` variable

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so I added the " (double-quotes) for $destcollfolder and I got the same error. I then added the " (double-quotes) to "$($sitecode):\DeviceCollection\Test Operational", ran the script and the collection moved where i wanted it to. Please write up an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see tells us that `$collID` is `$null` - indicating that the `Get-CMCollection` call didn't return anything.

As you've found, `SLS00287` is the Collection ID, not the name, so update that first:

```
$deviceCollection = Get-CMDeviceCollection -CollectionId -CollectionID $colltomove
```

Next, in order to have PowerShell correctly expand the `$siteCode` variable in `$destcollfolder`, you need to use double-quotes (`"`) rather than single-quotes (`'`):

```
$destcollfolder = "$($sitecode):\DeviceCollection\Test Operational"
```

Finally, I'd suggest taking advantage of pipeline binding when invoking `Move-CMObject`:

```
$deviceCollection |Move-CMObject -FolderPath $destcollfolder
```